# Display features OSM buildings

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, overpass-api, leaflet-plugins

Using Leaflet, I've [installed OSMBuildings](https://github.com/kekscom/osmbuildings), yet I'm unable to display buildings features although it's allowed on https://osmbuildings.org/
It seems like there is a latitude and longitude once we click on a building, do I need to use Overpass API or am I missing something else?

Comment: In what way is this question connected with QGIS? For implementation of displaying building features, see official example at https://osmbuildings.org/?lat=52.52111&lon=13.41078&zoom=16.0&tilt=30

Comment: @TomazicM It isn't, i've edited. I don't understand the official example, I've done what has been described for leaflet but there is no clear indication how I can display a building feature on click.

Comment: Logic of displaying clicked building features is in module https://osmbuildings.org/js/map.js.

Comment: @TomazicM Unfortunately, this implementation isn't specific to LeafletJS